# Existing CorrelationIDs in Application Insight

Tags: microservices, azure-application-insights

I am looking for best practices when handling a correlation id and logging to application insights.

My correlationID is a GUID that is first generated by a component outside of my control.  The correlationID stays with my event over message queue and web api calls.  This has been working for years, but now we are moving our logging into applicaiton insights.  I can't seem to find the best way to handle this.

The operation_parentID field in applicaiton insights is not suitable for this. By default, it will not accept a GUID value.  I can force it to use my GUID by changing Activity.DefaultIdFormat to Hierarchical, but this will interfer with the way application insisght manages the parentID.  It may be better to use a custom field for this.

This seems like a common scenario and should have been solved by now.  Can anyone point me to best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Application Insights follows W3C standard for correlation (https://www.w3.org/TR/trace-context/). This ensures interoperability if applications instrumented with different solutions.

There are three identifiers:

1. operation_Id (maps to trace-id in W3C). This defines a distributed transaction. Essentially this is GUID
2. id/operation_parentID (maps to id/parent-id in W3C). This is 8-byte array.

If existing correlationID defines a transaction then in this case you can achieve full parity by initializing operation_Id (through Activity).

If your correlationID represents id/parentId, i.e. one transaction is assembled by walking through id/parentId pairs, then I agree that it is not clear how to map it to W3C, and, as a result to Application Insights correlation.

Putting it in custom field will work (you also can do it through Activity and latest SDKs should even propagate it over the wire). Though curated experiences might not be able to visualize a transaction based on it, you still should be able to get everything through Kusto queries.